# Intellisense is lost for outside classes in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I have a file of a user control but it's not in a project, It's just read by a webpart in sharepoint and I was editing it but suddenly the AutoComplete for classes and variables like controls, SQL .. were gone. Only the common keywords are available like if, int, while ...
How can I get them back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new empy ASP.NET Website and then add existing item and choose this user control.

Comment: It didnt work, I realized it did a copy of it and didn't modify the original file.

Answer (score 1):

When you just have a single file, I believe Visual Studio just opens it in the **code editor**, and not the **IDE/Compiler**. The editor is just syntax highlighting basically, though you do have the drop downs available to navigate subclasses and methods. As when you're dealing with projects, it does use the IDE/Compiler, so Intellisense is available as well as full editor/ide features for that language.

Comment: So this mean that there is no solution? It used to work before though but I forgot how it was done and I closed it by mistake!